# Connecting to cassandra using pyspark

Tags: cassandra, pyspark

I am a beginner learning to work with spark and cassandra.
I am trying to connect to cassandra using pyspark. I am running cassandra 2.1 and spark 1.3.

I have cloned this repo https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra and followed instructions to get it working with spark shell as well as with spark-submit.

This is the command I am using ./bin/spark-submit --packages pyspark-cassandra:1.3 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1:9042 cassandra_test.py

and similarly with pyspark replacing spark-submit (without the script in the end)

I am getting this error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Provided Maven Coordinates must be in the form 'groupId:artifactId:version'. The coordinate provided is: pyspark-cassandra:1.3

I have tried to look for this error and go through related questions, but not able to get the connector working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but the spark packages page is here: http://spark-packages.org/package/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra

Seems to suggest:

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages TargetHolding:pyspark-cassandra:0.1.5`

Note the TargetHolding: bit. That might be it.